# Using table cell on dd

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put the items in line.

```
<dt>2018.05.10</dt>
  <dd>
    <a href="http://www.nippon-shindo.co.jp/pdf/2019_03tr.pdf" target="_blank">
      <p class="cell">
        <span class="orange">></span>中間期 決算短信 &ensp;[ PDF形式 146KB ]
      </p>
    </a>
</dd>

dl {
    display: table;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#summary .cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

but couldn't make those inline.

Comment: I don't see `#summary` anywhere in your code.

Comment: It's in the body tag. @RomeoSierra

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using HTML `table` or `div` elements for this? Because I feel like you are taking the hardest avenue to achieve what you need.

Comment: tell me more do you want 4 column or 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

dt {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

dd {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>2018.05.10</dt>
  <dd>

    <a href="http://www.nippon-shindo.co.jp/pdf/2019_03tr.pdf" target="_blank">
      <p class="cell">
        <span class="orange">></span>中間期 決算短信 &ensp;[ PDF形式 146KB ]
      </p>
    </a>

  </dd>
  <dd><img align="right" src="images/summary/pdf.png"></dd>
  <dt>2017.11.14</dt>
  <dd>

    <a href="http://www.nippon-shindo.co.jp/pdf/2019_03tr.pdf" target="_blank">
      <p class="cell">
        <span class="orange">></span>中間期 決算短信 &ensp;[ PDF形式 146KB ]
      </p>
    </a>

  </dd>
  <dd><img align="right" src="images/summary/pdf.png"></dd>

  <dt>2017.08.09</dt>
  <dd>

    <a href="http://www.nippon-shindo.co.jp/pdf/2019_03tr.pdf" target="_blank">
      <p class="cell">
        <span class="orange">></span>中間期 決算短信 &ensp;[ PDF形式 146KB ]
      </p>
    </a>

  </dd>
  <dd><img align="right" src="images/summary/pdf.png"></dd>


  <dt>2018.02.14</dt>
  <dd>

    <a href="http://www.nippon-shindo.co.jp/pdf/2019_03tr.pdf" target="_blank">
      <p class="cell">
        <span class="orange">></span>中間期 決算短信 &ensp;[ PDF形式 146KB ]
      </p>
    </a>

  </dd>
  <dd><img align="right" src="images/summary/pdf.png"></dd>

</dl>
```

Above i have css used float if you want 4 column you can play with css width and add dd

Two spaces - Type in `&ensp;`
Four spaces - Type in `&emsp;`
Tab - Type in `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Hope this will help you

Comment: Great :))))))))